# Rotating xlabels and decoupling x-axis title from labels

Tags: r, label, bar-chart, axis

I have been trying many things now but it just doesn't seem to work for me. I am looking for a solution to turn my x-axis labels (to 45°) and decoupling the title of the axis so that the labels don't overwrite my axis-title. This is the code I have

```
barplot(regions$no_rows,xlab="regions",ylab="number of occurences",
        main="XXX", 
        names.arg = regions$ID, las=2,cex.lab=1,cex.names= 0.65)
```

and this is what I get:[image]

I already cropped the margins and made the font of the labels smaller but isn't there a solution that it simply shows me the graph and then the axis titles apart from the labels.
With this solution I also don't get a 45° inclination. I tried several codes for that as well, as for example this one:

```
regions = regions[with(regions, order(-no_rows)), ] 
end_point = 0.5 + nrow(regions) + nrow(regions)-1 
barplot(regions$no_rows, col="grey50", 
        main="XXX",
        ylab="occurences", ylim=c(0,5+max(regions$no_rows)),
        xlab = "regions",
        space=1)
text(seq(-0.5,end_point,by=2), par("usr")[3], 
     srt = 45, adj= 1, xpd = TRUE,
     labels = paste(regions$ID), cex=0.65)
```

didn't look nice either because again the x-axis title was too close to the labels but also the labels were too close to the bars:
[image]

Thank you so much for your help!
P.s.: lets say this is the df i got

```
regions
ID    no_rows
A       100
B        8
C        50
......
```

Answer (score 1):

Staying base `barplot` you can switch off labels and axis and make custom ones like so.

```
op <- par(mar=c(6, 4, 5, 4))
b <- barplot(Employed ~ Month, data=dat1,  # store invisible output
             xlab="",  # switch off axis title
             xaxt="n", # switch off labels
             col="orange",
             main="My main title here"
)
# labels
text(x=b,  # us inv. output for label positions
     y=-4, # shuft them somewhat down
     srt=45, adj= 1, xpd=TRUE,
     labels=dat1$Month, cex=0.65) 
# axis title
mtext("Month", 1, 4)
par(op)
```

[image]

---

*Data*

```
dat1 <- structure(list(Employed = c(63.221, 63.639, 64.989, 63.761, 66.019, 
67.857, 68.169, 66.513, 68.655, 69.564, 69.331, 70.551), Month = c("foooooooo_January", 
"foooooooo_February", "foooooooo_March", "foooooooo_April", "foooooooo_May", 
"foooooooo_June", "foooooooo_July", "foooooooo_August", "foooooooo_September", 
"foooooooo_October", "foooooooo_November", "foooooooo_December"
)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative in `ggplot2`**

I'm not sure it is exactly what you are looking for, but if you don't have to stay with `barplot`, you can solve this probleam easily with `ggplot2` by using the argument `axis.text.x` in the `theme` function that allow to change the angle of x labeling and adjust their position to not overlap with the axis:

```r
regions <- data.frame(ID = LETTERS[1:3],
                      rows = c(100,8,50))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(regions, aes(x = reorder(ID,-rows), y = rows))+
  geom_col()+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))+
  xlab("New Name")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        axis.line.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  ggtitle("Main Title")
```

[image]

Comment: two questions: How can I rename the axis titles in this case? And can I make the background disappear?

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly. Briefly, you can use the `theme_classic()` that is quite close of the `base` r plot theme and also use `xlab` to rename x axis title.

Comment: thank you. Now it unfortunately cuts off the top of the graph, and I still don't have my main title. Plus is there a way to change the ylim, so that it starts at 0?

Comment: I added couple of parameters to make the plot looks more similar to a barplot from `r` base plot. Otherwise, I think @jay.sf has answered your question.